# Loading language text in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have hook controller class given below

```
<?php
class LanguageLoader
{
   function initialize() {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->load->helper('language');

        $site_lang = $ci->session->userdata('site_lang');
        if ($site_lang) {
            $ci->lang->load('main',$ci->session->userdata('site_lang'));
        } else {
            $ci->session->set_userdata('site_lang','english');
            $ci->lang->load('main','english');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

This is language switcher class

```
<?php

class languageSwitcher extends NQF_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this -> load -> helper('url');

    }

    function switchLanguage($language = "", $url) {
        $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "english";
        $this -> session -> set_userdata('site_lang', $language);
        redirect($url);
    }

}
?>
```

I have placed language text in header like this

```
<?php echo $this->lang->line('contact_location'); ?>
```

In header, I got the appropriate text respective to language loaded. But when i keep same  lang->line('contact_location'); ?> in footer, I get blank. Why is it so?

Comment: where are you loading language file?

Comment: I have made main_lang.php in both english and chinese folder inside language directory.

Comment: can you show how you are loading template? Hope you are loading this main_lang.php in autoloca. right?

Comment: The main question is that I am getting the text from language file in header but not in footer...

Comment: @atomaprchya any solution that you can share with us? I have the same issue as well.